# Mootools-more.js conflicting with Bootstrap Button dropdowns

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery, mootools, bootstrap

I was migrating a component from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. I noticed a weird effect after opening and closing a button dropdown => the button disappears.

[image]

Upon investigating, it looks like jQuery is conflicting (similar to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3436) with Mootools. This is not a conflict in the general sense (it's not causing JavaScript errors in the logs).

jQuery is triggering a 'hide' event and MooTools is catching it first.

[image]

Comment: I have also migrating from b2 to b3 with mootools and jquery, any good workaround?? 

`window.addEvent('domready', function () { Element.prototype.hide = function () { if (this.hasClass('btn-group')) { return this; } this.setStyle('display', 'none'); };
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the only workaround I've found so far (opened for review):

```
// MooTools
window.addEvent('domready',function() {

    Element.prototype.hide = function() {
        alert('Intercepted');
        // Do nothing
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mootools.

It's already slated for removal in Joomla's roadmap, jQuery being the preferred core option and Bootstrap have made quite clear that Bootstrap is not intended to be run alongside other other javascript libraries.

Comment: Totally agree with you. The question is tightly related to 2.5. which still has a lot of dependencies on MooTools (such as the calendar).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solve this by doing following:

**in html**

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#link1" data-toggle="tab">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link2" data-toggle="tab">Link1</a></li>   
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="link1">
        LINK1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="web_design">
        LINK2
    </div>
</div>
```

**in js**

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {    
    Element.prototype.hide = function() {
       $(function () { 
         $('#myTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
       });    
    };
});
```

Comment: Try it by creating a custom module. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found this looking for a solution to this
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=903425&p=3474051#p3474051
the same issue with disappearing tabs on frontend editing 
unset mootools using these 
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=813835

I think in may case it's 
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);